# Comunicating between layers in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

Reading the literature of DDD I came up with the following layers:

- `Application` Outsider World (Controllers, Crons, etc)
- `Application Services` (or UseCases) - which orchestrates multiple Domain Services or Infrastructure Services. They are called from `Outside World`. They know what things have to be done
- `Domain Services` - which contains how the things are done (relying on repository interfaces)

**Question**: Is there any best practices how to communicate between layers?

What I know:
- `Application services` should return "wanted data" to be exposed and some of "success" of the transaction (warnings, error, infos)
- The data that an `Application Service` returns, should be gathered from `Domain Services` and/or `Infrastructure Services` and composed togather.

```
Controller <-> Application Service <-> Domain Service          
                                   <-> Infrastructure Service
```

These are some of my ambiguous thoughts:

- Should all methods on `Application Service` have a specific DTO that contain the "request" as a parameter?  Like `AddItemToCardCommandDto` (that encapsulated all the needed data). How about a generic `ResultObject` that have only a couple of methods like `getResult` and `hasErrorrs` or `getMessages`?
- How should return `DomainService` data and errors? Should they Return errors by  exception? That seems odd because to me Bussines Validation should be called in `DomainServices` as they are part of business rules.

Comment: DDD is not a programming technique.  Perhaps you're referring to  [Multi-Layered Architecture?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayered_architecture)

Comment: DDD it is more  "approach to software development". From what I understood I came up with some layers. Can you detail more about your comment?

Comment: Multi-Layered Architecture comes with its own set of "best practices."   Have you studied those practices yet?  DDD doesn't have anything to say about how your software layers communicate, other than to possibly establish which layers you're going to use.

Comment: OK, can you share some of these best practices that apply to my question? I have not studied in particular this subject

Comment: Maybe you should.... What *is* your question, exactly?  Can you state it in such a way that isn't a big list of things or requires a book chapter to answer?

Comment: I got the hint from your previous answers.  The question was "Question: Is there any best practices how to communicate between layers". It was actually formatted with bold in the questions body.  Probably your answer will bring some experience gathered along with links of literature.

Answer (score 1):

I would say having DTOs would dilute the design of the Model. We can get away with having to not use DTOs by refactoring our Model and designing our APIs to use the refactored models objects.

The answer to query 1: 
The application-service can have methods with a signature

```
void addItemToCard(Item item, Card card);
```

The methods can have a return type or not, based on the kind of operation we are looking to perform and the data we want to transfer across layers. You need to make sure that each layer has a specified interface and different layers speak to each other through that interface for all components in the application.

Eg:

```
List<Items> getItemsOnCard(String cardID);
//returns list of items or empty list if no item can be found.

List<Offers> getOffersApplicableOnCardForItem()
//should return list of Offers or empty list if no item can be found. Should not return a null if no items can be found
```

Making sure that all methods comply with the same behavior is more important in keeping the interface intact.

Answer to query 2:

I think DDD recommends having 3 layers if I remember it right. Having domain intelligence in the application layer helps and signifies that your application is bound to the domain and has a bounded context. You might add additional layers if you feel that 3 is not sufficient. Exceptions can be used to cascade information across layers. Data can be contained inside placeholders of custom exceptions for business.

I hope this answers some of the questions you have.

Answer (score 0):

The possible answers to any of your questions do not have much to do with DDD, but with software architecture and design.

In software architecture, there are no such things as "best practices", but certainly "problems" and "principles" to keep in mind during designing, and "patterns" to apply addressing these "problems" accordingly to these "principles" in order to produce a "solution".

One of the things I try to point out with that above is that in software architecture, there are no generic "silver bullet" solutions. In fact, very often, you have to trade off principles for others, AKA compromises/contextual decisions. So...

> Is there any best practices how to communicate between layers?

Literally, no.

In real world, the first "principles" you have to keep in mind are the "budget" and the release "deadline" of the project you're designing a solution for. Depending on these ressources (principles), you'd typically go either for a simple 3 tier architecture or a robust clean/hexagonal one.

But to address your real questions, let's assume you have unlimited ressources...

> Should all methods on Application Service have a specific DTO that contain the "request" as a parameter? Like AddItemToCardCommandDto (that encapsulated all the needed data). How about a generic ResultObject that have only a couple of methods like getResult and hasErrorrs or getMessages?

Why do we generally bother creating data models? Why don't we pass all around plain generic arrays/objects instead?

One element of answer would be "typing". Another one would be that such `UseCaseRequest` model is not a *vulgar DTO* you would genericize.

Your specific model might be genericizable at this time, but in future it might change, encapsulating specific behavior and specific data with no problem... If on the other hand that has to happen within a generic model, well it's not generic anymore, you need a specific model, but the generic one is already passed all around... It might be tedious to refactor all depending components... You have then what we call "rigid code" problem that you try to solve accordingly to "principles" you should have thought about during initial design.

Model types are semantically and polymorphically meaningful in your application, domain layers, and even in tools, among which your IDE... Although the model type itself is not generic, its specificity allows some degree of genericity of the code manipulating it... For example, we can imagine a generic `PostUseCase` composed of and calling polymorphically specific `PostDataTypeUSeCase` depending dynamically on that model type.

I certainly forget other benefits...

Meanwhile, we can reduce annoyance introduced by specific model typing multiple ways...

Some code generator tools can be used to generate basic specific model types and components depending on them like use cases, streamlining new domain model implementations.

Some [object mapper](https://github.com/opportus/object-mapper) tools can be used to decouple mapping logic of different model types from your codebase.

> How should return DomainService data and errors? Should they Return errors by exception? That seems odd because to me Bussines Validation should be called in DomainServices as they are part of business rules.

Not sure what you find odd which seems what you expect...

However, there are many ways for the upper layer, I assume your `Application` layer's controller, to get `DomainService`'s reply.

More sophistically, you could return the reply to a presenter like in Uncle Bob's Clean Architecture diagram below. This solution adds degree of decoupling between the two layer, complying with the [Inversion Of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) principle.

[image]